# What the minimum hardware requirement for Mongo Arbiter node?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-arbiter

In mongoDB replica set - we can have 1 arbiter node for voting purpose only.

I want to know the minimum hardware requirement for Arbiter node in terms of:

RAM,CPU,Cores and IOPS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 core| 2GB will suffice for arbite

Answer (score -2):

If you want to run it on the cheapest possible hardware (like the smallest available aws instance size) you can certainly try it and see what happens.

Comment: This "answer" doesn't provide any useful information and would be better suited as a comment.